# Append the data to existing json file

Tags: python, json, file-io

I have an existing JSON file and trying to add string into file. But as soon as I write a JSON file the new line characters do disappear in the JSON file and format gets changed.

Below is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import json

userinput = raw_input('Enter the name of a file a you want to read: ')
with open(userinput) as json_data:
    s = json_data.read()
    data = json.loads(s)
    print data['classes']
json_data.close()


class_add = raw_input('Enter the name of a class a you want to add: ')
if class_add in data['classes']:
    print "Class %s already exists, doing nothing." % class_add
else:
    data['classes'].append(class_add)
    print json.dumps(data)
    print data['classes']
    with open(userinput, 'w') as json_data:
        json_data.write(json.dumps(data))
    json_data.close()
```

---

One more import thing here is, that the formatting of the JSON file. So by default we will be having the file in the below formatting.

```
# cat test.json
{
    "selinux_mode": "enforcing",
    "cis_manages_auditd_service": true,
    "classes": [ "basic", "admin", "lvm"]
}
#
```

But once we add the class it becomes the following.

```
# cat test.json 
{"cis_manages_auditd_service": true, "classes": [ "basic", "admin", "lvm"], "selinux_mode": "enforcing"}
```

Is there any way that I can keep the JSON whitespace and new line character as it is without changing anything.

Comment: Why do you call `json_data.close()`, that filedescriptor closes at the end of the `with` statement.

Comment: didn't know that when we use with statement it closes the file automatically. From now on, I won't be using that. thanks

Comment: You cannot control the formatting of `json.dumps()` to the degree you want. Readability of the output can be improved by adding an `indent=4` argument to the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON doesn't need a particular layout, but for slightly less bad human readability you can supply `indent=2`

```
import sys
import json

userinput = raw_input('Enter the name of a file a you want to read: ')
with open(userinput) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    print(data['classes'])


class_add = raw_input('Enter the name of a class a you want to add: ')
if class_add in data['classes']:
    print("Class {} already exists, doing nothing.".format(class_add))
else:
    data['classes'].append(class_add)
    json.dump(data, sys.stdout, indent=2)
    print(data['classes'])
    with open(userinput, 'w') as json_data:
        json.dump(data, json_data, indent=2)
```

Please note that if you are using the `with` statement to open a file, you should not close it explicitly (that is done at the end of the block, whether there is an exception or not).

If you are writing to a file, instead of processing the JSON as string, you should also refrain from using `json.dumps(data)` and use `json.dump(data, file_pointer)` instead. The same holds for `json.loads()` and `json.load()`.

Comment: Ok. let me try to modify the code and re-run again to test it. thanks

Comment: so the classes stanza are printed with long space. is there any way we can cut new line character for each element inside that.

Comment: I also ten to use `print` as function (`print()`), you will have to use that when you switch to Python 3, so get used to the parenthesis (and add `from __future__ import print_function` to the top of all your `.py` files)

Comment: I don't think you have that fine grained control with JSON. If this is all about readability I would look at YAML instead of using JSON. With ruamel.yaml (of which I am the author), you can preserve layout and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `indent` argument to function [`json.dumps()`](http://fs22.clicknupload.net:182/d/j25yr2vjlvyd7tr7wha4fmcqat5tjxz36erbscvht55bn7tqnpldh3gdc3hrjyvypfd4voij/m.S02E08.480p.u766145.Rapidmoviez.com.rar) to an integer representing the number of spaces to indent.

This will still modify the formatting of the output to something like this:

```
import json

s = '''{
    "selinux_mode": "enforcing",
    "cis_manages_auditd_service": true,
    "classes": [ "basic", "admin", "lvm"]
}'''

data = json.loads(s)

>>> print(json.dumps(data))
{"cis_manages_auditd_service": true, "classes": ["basic", "admin", "lvm"], "selinux_mode": "enforcing"}

>>> print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
{
    "cis_manages_auditd_service": true, 
    "classes": [
        "basic", 
        "admin", 
        "lvm"
    ], 
    "selinux_mode": "enforcing"
}
```

The difference between the original and the updated version is that the `classes` list is now displayed across multiple lines.